# Woocommerce CSV Headers for categories not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, import

I'm trying importing product with Import feature woocommerce

Here the CSV data:
post_title, type,   category_ids,   regular_price
Intel - Pentium G3250,simple,intel|1155|processors,860000

The issues is products that are imported, do not fit the category that writed on CSV Data.

I tried tax:cat header and still not get the result that i wanted, is that header column documentation is out of date or something? [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-column-header-reference/)

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJCrY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved this issues with changing delimiter csv from comma( , ) sign to semicolon( ; )

I realized that to add multiple cat on product cat is use comma to separated cat like this: cat1,cat2,cat3

so My csv look like this:

post_title; type; category_ids; regular_price
tes produk;simple;car,red,machine;860000

Hope it helps :)